# To Stay on same page after refreshing in AngularJS? It is redirecting to Login page

Tags: angularjs

Here is My controller Code. I am using session storage and $rootScope but $rootScope is setting all the values back to false after refresh. When I use only sessionStorage it is setting session values but not redirecting to landing page from login page. Can someone help me on this?

```js
function LoginCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $window, $location, $http, $state, loginService, $cookies, $sessionStorage) {
  $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
  $rootScope.registereduser = false;
  $rootScope.registration = false;


  $scope.changeState = function() {
    $rootScope.registration = true;
    $state.go('register');

  }
  $scope.logout = function() {

    $window.localStorage.clear();
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    $rootScope.registereduser = false;
    $rootScope.registration = false;
  }
  $scope.gotoHome = function() {

    $window.localStorage.clear();
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    $rootScope.registereduser = false;
    $rootScope.registration = false;
  }


  $scope.showGroup = function(userName, password) {
    $scope.userId = userName;
    $scope.password = password;
    if ((userName == null || userName == '') && (password == null || password == '')) {
      alert("please enter valid credentials");
      $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    } else

      $http.post("./rest/jsonServices/authentication?userId=" + $scope.userId + "&password=" + $scope.password).success(function(data) {
        var landingPage = '';
        $scope.inValidCredentials = false;
        $rootScope.role = data.role;

        if (data != null && data.accessible == true) {

          //    sessionStorage.user = JSON.stringify(data);

          sessionStorage.loggedIn = true;
          $rootScope.loggedIn = sessionStorage.loggedIn;

          $rootScope.loggedInuserId = userName;

          $rootScope.menuType = data.defaultMenuType;
          $scope.operational = data.operational;
          $scope.lifeCycle = data.lifeCycle;
          $scope.qbot = data.qbot;
          $scope.admin = data.admin;

          if ($scope.admin) {
            $state.go('admin');
            $scope.menubar = false;
          } else if ($scope.operational) {
            $state.go('dashboard');
            $scope.var1 = true;
          } else if ($scope.lifeCycle) {
            $state.go('lifecycle');
            $scope.menubar = false;
          } else if ($scope.qbot) {
            $scope.menubar = false;
            $state.go('qbot')
          }

        } else if (data != null && data.accessible == false) {
          $rootScope.registereduser = true;
          $rootScope.loggedIn = false;

        } else {

          alert("Invalid Credentials");
          data.message = "Invalid UserID or Password";
          $scope.error = data.message;
        }

      }).error(function(data) {

        alert("Please Enter Valid Credentials");

      });
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in your console when redirection fails?

Comment: No error found but i can see the session values are being stored but i couldn't make page to stay on same

Comment: Session value is present but redirecting to login page Kxng Kombian  Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: are the state names valid?

Comment: yeah all the state names are valid and states are present as it it but redirects to login page

Comment: You're injecting $sessionStorage which I assume means that you are using the ngStorage service.  If so, while you are injecting it properly, when using it in your code you're referring to sessionStorage instead of $sessionStorage.  Also, $rootScope is stored in memory that is cleared on browser window close or refresh.

Comment: What should I replace  $rootScope  with? It is clearing when i refresh.  It should not happen. Can you suggest solution?

Comment: @jayakrishnadoddala - you're on the right track using the $sessionStorage service but you need to read up on it and implement it correctly.

Comment: $sessionStorage I'm able to store the $sessionStorage.loggedIn= true in the session but redirection is happening to login page since I am using $rootScope below. If I am not using $rootScope only $sessionStorge is not helping me to login at all. Can you help on this point @jbrown

Comment: @jayakrishnadoddala - what do you mean "not helping me to login"?  My recommendation is to just use sessionStorage and forget about rootScope. If you want actual you need to share your current code, preferably in a plunk.